# Saving DensityPlot as vector graphics in Mathematica 12.1 and above

Tags: plotting, export

I want to save `DensityPlot[]` as vector graphics to PDF. As an example, let's save this plot:

```
DensityPlot[x y, {x, 0, 3.5}, {y, 0, 3}, ImageSize -> 220]
```

Then, I click on "Save Graphics As..." and save to a PDF, remembering to select "Use Highest Quality Vector Representation" in the saving options.

[image: Example density plot]

In MMA 12.0 this saves as vector graphics without issues. However, in MMA 12.1 and 12.2, even with the "Use Highest Quality Vector Representation" option, the plot saves as rasterized image encapsulated in a PDF. How can I save this plot as vector graphics in MMA 12.1 and above?

Comment: It's a bug and I don't believe there is a workaround for it.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried exporting with AllowRasterization set to False, printing the selection to a file, both didn't work and produced a rasterised image.